# Join DB tables on Drupal

Tags: php, mysql, database, drupal, drupal-7

i have a watchdog table and i create a distinct table which i have the unique variables from watchdog with their wids as key. What i want is to join the 2 tables (distinct and watchdog) in order to join all the values with unique variables. i did this:

```
$query = db_select('distinct', 'di');
    $query -> join('watchdog', 'wa', 'di.wid = wa.wid');
    $query -> fields('u', array('variables', 'type', 'severity','message', 'wid', 'timestamp'));
    $result = $query->execute();
  }
```

I cannot find where is my fault

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your field alias `u` doesn't exist. You declared `di` and `wa` but not `u`. Change this to `wa`, I suppose the selected columns are from the `watchdog` table.

```
$query = db_select('distinct', 'di');
$query->join('watchdog', 'wa', 'di.wid = wa.wid');
$query->fields('wa', array('variables', 'type', 'severity','message', 'wid', 'timestamp'));

$result = $query->execute();
```